# Sd card is readable but,not able to write or format the card

Tags: sd-card

I am using a Transcend class 4 8gb SD card. I am not able to erase the SD using my phone.

1) All the files can be accessed. I cannot send or delete files in the SD card.

2) When I delete the files and folders,they come back after the phone restarts.

3) Gparted is not detecting this card. I tried in a Windows system too.

Can anyone please explain how I might format this card? I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: It's  an issue related with the card rather that the system it seems. Can you connect the sd card directly via an adaptor? I believe you're using USB with the connection right now. Your sd card is read only right now, so you can't modify it.

Comment: I can ask for a replacement but i dont want to give this card coz data can be accesseed.

Comment: Can you connect it via SD card port on the pc?

Comment: No matter how much i format. The data keeps coming back. I tried formatting using gparted.

Comment: answer my question, can you connect it via port on the PC?

Comment: Yes. I connect using "usb storage" option when i plugin. Thats the only way i connect

Comment: i'm not talking about USB, SD card reader is what im talking about

Comment: Yes. I am talking about connecting my sd card through phone.

Comment: You need to connect that with SD card you can't modify SD card through phone

Answer (score 1):

If it's a standerd SD-card then look for a phisical switch on the side of the card. If it was broken off then you can put some tape over the opening and you should be able to write to it.

Comment: There is no physical switch.

Comment: Its a transcend class4 sd card. There is no physical switch

Comment: yup.  That did it.  I plus 1 this.